# Firefox browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders. No Clue why nothing happens

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

So, this is about extensions for Browsers and trying to intercept Headers and interact with them before a GET request gets made.
I'm just trying some new things out, and wanted to play around with the webRequest.onBefoerSendHeaders, however it doesn't seem to do anything.

I just want to log something to the console if a certain header exists.
Here is my code:

```js
var requestFilter = {
    urls: ["random Site"]
}

var extraInfoSpec = ['requestHeaders', 'blocking']

handler = function(details) {

    var headers = details.requestHeaders;

    for (var i = 0, l = headers.length; i < l; ++i) {
        if (headers[i].name == 'User-Agent') {
            console.log("It works!")
            break;
        }
    }

};

browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(handler, requestFilter, extraInfoSpec);
```

Here is the manifest:

```
{

"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "test",
"version": "1.0",

"description": "test",

"icons": {
  "48": "empty"
},

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://random Site/*"],
    "js": ["header.js"]
  }
],

"permissions": [ 
    "webRequest", 
    "webRequestBlocking", 
    "<all_urls>",
]}
```

I do know there are some unused permissions and the speficied URL etc. does not exist.

Does somebody know why it does nothing? It is supossed to run in Firefox and Chrom.

Comment: "_It doesn't work_" is not a sufficient description of the problem you face. The code you've provided, and the syntax errors it includes, did not come from the link you state it came from. In addition, you've not discussed the concept of a background script or browser extension in your question. Please provide the implementation details you are using, fix the syntax errors, and if you desire, indicate the source from which  you actually copy-n-pasted this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `manifest` file it looks like you are attempting to use the `webRequest` API with a content script. However `browser.webRequest` is not available to content scripts and it will need to be converted to a background script in order to work.

I would recommend removing the content script configuration and configuring the code to run as a background script.

```json
"background": {
  "scripts": ["header.js"]
},
```